# Why these Gitlab jobs are exiting with 127 error code

Tags: docker, gitlab, centos8

So .. I am trying to run some jobs for the execution of a project, and the first time I tried to run it through the .gitlab-ci file it took a long time to execute it and presented error 127 during execution. This was the log that came out:

[Log 1](https://pastebin.com/CMq663Re)

Then I realized that it was something related to / bin / sh and tried to run it again, and instead of using apt-get, I used yum to install the dependencies. But the same error happened, here is the log of the last attempt:

[Log 2](https://pastebin.com/R6LLy3sy)

I have no idea how to solve this, because my experience in this area is for beginners and I thank you in advance for anyone who can help me.

Comment: 1. What the OS did you use for gitlab-runner ?

2. Please show your .gitlab-ci.yml file

Comment: The OS that I used is CentOS 8 and this is the .gitlab-ci.yml that i'm using now:

[link](https://pastebin.com/iTDKqQNf)

and this is the current error log:

[link](https://pastebin.com/xGsz0LZ1)

Comment: At now your problems are here:
`$ npm run build
> clinica-escola@1.4.5-SNAPSHOT build /builds/root/testest
> ng build
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property Minus of undefined
See "/tmp/ng-fHBflf/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! clinica-escola@1.4.5-SNAPSHOT build: ng build
npm ERR! Failed at the clinica-escola@1.4.5-SNAPSHOT build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-04T16_16_05_437Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that. But the problem for me now is to access this log. I've tried to do throug the gitlab container and the runner container, but I couldn't find this log